# How to create a database project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide

I'm migrating a solution which contains some C# projects from Visual Studio 2008 to VS2013. The migration went fine, with a few adjustments, but there's also a .dbp project (database project, from VS2008), which refuses to migrate / load in VS2013.

The closest project type I found in this newer version is "SQL Server Database Project", I've created one and added my existing .sql script files, but this project type (.sqlproj) appears to be something different. For example, VS 2008's "database project" does not *build*. Also, I had a hard time trying to add a reference to my existing SQL database running under SQLExpress.

I've also set BuildAction = None to all my script files, and now I can open each of them manually and execute. But still, **I'd like to select multiple files and execute them all at once**. Seems I'm missing something.

So, is there a way to accomplish that?